# different result when echo some string using single/double quotes

Tags: shell

echo some string when use single quotes it's printed successfully

```
➜  ~ echo 'LOGIN_IDENTITY=sdf!121sdf$78sd!8'
LOGIN_IDENTITY=sdf!121sdf$78sd!8
```

but when use double quotes, it cannot be printed successfully and changed to another strange commands

```
➜  ~ echo "LOGIN_IDENTITY=sdf!121sdf$78sd!8"
➜  ~ echo "LOGIN_IDENTITY=sdffind . -name 'application.properties' | xargs  grep 'login'sdf$78sdawk '{print "\""$0"\""}' a"
```

So what's wrong with double quotes?

Comment: check history of your command prompt and check 121st command you had hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of [`Parameter Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in shell, when you have an `!` character within the double-quotes, it tried to expand it to have a value.

Following excerpt from `man bash` page, [`history-expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) subsection:

> History expansions are introduced by the appearance of the history expansion 
>   character, which is ‘!’ by default. Only ‘\’ and ‘'’ may be used to escape the > history expansion character, but the history expansion character is also 
>   treated as quoted if it immediately precedes the closing double quote in a 
>   double-quoted string.

You can avoid the expansion either by using single-quotes(`'`)

```
$ echo "LOGIN_IDENTITY=sdf!121sdf$78sd!8"
-bash: !121: event not found
```

change the above assignment to

```
$ echo "LOGIN_IDENTITY=sdf"'!'"121sdf$78sd"'!'"8"
LOGIN_IDENTITY=sdf!121sdf8sd!8
```

Notice the single-quote around the `!` character.